$R^2$ for both zero-inflated count and zero-inflation models
I am calculating $R^2$ for a zero-inflated model in R using the function r2_zeroinflated (model). From this, you get a $R^2$ value for the model. However, I would like to get an $R^2$ value for both the count and zero-inflation parts separately. Does anybody know how to get this?
For reference - this is my model (density here is a count):
NumberofPlantsModel <- zeroinfl(Area_Density ~Location + Height, 
                           data = dat, dist = "negbin")

If anybody know of a better goodness to fit test I could use for my zero-inflated model, I would also be interested in this.

I'm not sure what you propose makes sense. This would in essence require fitting two separate models to get the $R^2$, which I think wouldn't capture the point of the model. You could maybe find a way to partition the deviance attributed to each model compared to the total deviance, but I'm not sure that is possible or makes sense to do. I'd be happy to see if somebody else has a better idea though.

Inclined to agree with @Shawn Hemelstrand that the purpose of the model is, fundamentally, to fit both equations simultaneously.
That said, partitioning the $R^2$ into components ascribed to each equation is possible. Take the reproducible example below derived from the example provided by performance::r2_zeroinflated:
require(Formula)
pscl::zeroinfl(
  art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + ment | kid5 + phd,
  data = pscl::bioChemists
) |>
  performance::r2_zeroinflated()

Which produces
# R2 for Zero-Inflated and Hurdle Regression
       R2: 0.180
  adj. R2: 0.175

This $R^2$ value can be partitioned using the domir::domir package's formula_list method combining all the elements in one of the equations into a set as below:
domir::domir(
  domir::formula_list(
    art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + ment,
    inflate ~ kid5 + phd
  ),
  \(fml) {
    fml |> 
      domir::fmllst2Fml(drop_lhs = 2L) |>
      pscl::zeroinfl(data = pscl::bioChemists) |>
      performance::r2_zeroinflated() |>
      _[[1]]
  },
  .set = 
    list(
      count = domir::formula_list(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + ment),
      inflate = domir::formula_list(inflate ~ kid5 + phd)
    )
)

which produces
Overall Value:      0.1797548 

General Dominance Values:
        General Dominance Standardized Ranks
count         0.173415934   0.96473612     1
inflate       0.006338851   0.03526388     2

Conditional Dominance Values:
        Include At: 1 Include At: 2
count     0.173212911   0.173618957
inflate   0.006135828   0.006541874

Complete Dominance Proportions:
          > count > inflate
count >        NA         1
inflate >       0        NA

A full decomposition of the $R^2$ based on dominance analysis/Shapley values.
Some of the concepts behind this idea are discussed in this work
which discusses an example with a zero inflated model.

It is true that you should primarily use the result from fitting both count and zeroinflation. However, as I frequently get somewhat contradicting results especially concerning significance between count and zero shown inthe summary, I want to compare r2 values between the two to see if this may clarify some of the issues.
Thank you very much for the answer!
This was exactly what I was looking for.
